# Android Sqlite Load Extension / Mimic Stored Procedures

Tags: android, sqlite, stored-procedures

I am looking to mimic the behavior of a stored procedure in a sqlite database running on an Android device.  I am aware that SQLite does not do 'stored procedures', but it is possible to achieve the same effect through either loading some custom extension or by other means.  For example, in SQLite ADO.Net you can create user defined functions that are bound the Sqlite core at runtime.

Is there an equivalent for Androids flavor of sqlite?  Can I load an existing extension (in .so format) or write some type of Java based function that can behave like a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an equivalent for Androids flavor of sqlite?

No, sorry.

> Can I load an existing extension (in .so format) or write some type of Java based function that can behave like a stored procedure?

No, sorry.